# Where to find pg_config?

Tags: python, postgresql-9.1, psycopg2

I am installing `psycopg2` on Machine. I installed dmg file of PostGre 9.x for 10.6OSX. Upon installing psycopg2 it says `pg_config` is missing. How to I set the path?

Comment: There's no such thing as "Postgre 9.x". Going by your tags, I'm guessing you meant PostgreSQL 9.1 ? How, exactly, did you install it and from where? Do you mean Postgres.app ?

Answer (score 0):

`pg_config` is inside the installed app. If you temporarily add the directory it’s in to `$PATH`, then the installer can find it.

```
$ PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH" pip install --user psycopg2
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
...
Successfully installed psycopg2
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: This is what I find when I do ls. no such app with that name:

*Application Stack Builder.app* *Documentation*   *Reload Configuration.app* *SQL Shell (psql).app*  *pgAdmin III.app*